# upper bound to product of square roots as function of their arguments

Tags: inequality, reference-request, exponentiation, products

Given two positive reals $x$, $y$, I want to find the strictest upper bound to $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$
in the form $h(kx + g(y))$. where $k$ must be a real and $g$ and $h$ can be any functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

It is pretty straightforward to show
$$
\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} \le \min_{\alpha>0}\left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}x + \frac{1}{\alpha\sqrt{2}}y\right)\enspace.
$$

Is it possible to find stricter bounds?

Any reference would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$x\geq 0$$ and $$y\geq 0$$ thus we get after AM-GM:
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\le \frac{1}{2}(x+y)$$

Comment: What would be a lower bound for $\sqrt(x * y)$?